# using savepoints in sqlite from command line

Tags: bash, sqlite, testing, bats-core

I am using a bash script (specifically, [bats](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core)) to test some code I wrote.

Because I want to avoid interference in the tests, I am using setup and teardown functions (which bats provides) like this:

```
setup() {
  sqlite3 test.db "SAVEPOINT pre_test"
}

teardown() {
  sqlite3 test.db "ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT pre_test"
}
```

Unfortunately, when rolling back, I get:

```
Error: no such savepoint: pre_test
```

If, however, I start an interactive session in SQLite, I can use savepoints as I would expect. I guess that this means all savepoints are forgotten about after the command-line program exits.

Is there any way of working around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the [documentation refers to savepoints as similar to transactions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html) my impression is that a savepoint does not persist beyond a single sqlite session.

The documentation makes no note of this in particular, but the [exhaustive explanation of how transactions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) are handled implies throughout the this ought all be contained in single session.

Given that an inactive database can be trivially copied `cp precious.db pre_test.db` it seems that such would be the obvious way to effect the setup. Teardown is merely `rm pretest.db`.

Comment: *facepalm* how did I not think of that. Thanks!